# Цвет в Tkinter.Scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter

Как задать цвет скроллбару текстового поля в Tkinter? Все атриббуты переюзал, не выходит - цвет дефолтный...

Comment: Не могу коментить , поэтому пишу в ответы.
Выложи код 

Comment: Параметры виджета можно получить с помощью метода `.config()

    for i in widget.config().keys():
        print i, sx.config()[i]

Comment: аттрибут bg не меняет цвет! Как, впрочем, и остальные! Может, приведешь рабочий пример?

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь они жёлтые

```
from Tkinter import *
r = Tk()
t = Text(r, heigh=10, width=30)
t.grid(row=0, column=0)
sx = Scrollbar(r, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=t.xview, bg='yellow', troughcolor='red')
sy = Scrollbar(r, orient=VERTICAL, command=t.yview, bg='yellow')
sx.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)
sy.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
t['yscrollcommand'] = sy.set
t['xscrollcommand'] = sx.set
```

Добавлено. 
[image]

Comment: Ничего подобного!!! Дефолтный!!!

Comment: Добавил скриншот. Какая система, какой питон. Ну можно еще указать версию tcl/tk

Comment: Tk 8.5, Python 2.7.2, XP...